# Dependent Dropdown in JSF fails validation

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, drop-down-menu, selectonemenu

I have two dependent dropdowns on a JSF page that work fine. I use a valueChangeListener on the first dropdown that populates the List backing the second dropdown.

However when I try to submit my form it's failing JSF validation. From testing I think the problem is that when the page loads my dependent dropdown list is empty, then I populate it after the first dropdown has a selection made. However none of the values now in the dependent list were in the list when the page loaded so it's fails validation. I have confirmed this by using a constructor to set up the list with all the possible values when the page loads and it makes my problem go away however this isn't a possible solution as loading up all the values would kill the performance of my page.

Any ideas how I can get it working?

Regards,
Kevin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is EXACTLY the use case for a view scoped bean. Using a request scoped bean in such case is going against the grain of JSF (possible, but painful - like using a hedgehog as a bath sponge).

If there are any problems with such solutions, then tell us, there should be a way of mitigating them; the point is, you should use the view scope and solve any problems you might have with that, and not try to run away from it.

Comment: Yes this solved my problem. I changed the scope from request to view. I'm new to using JSF so still getting my head around it. I'm still not sure why View scope works and Request scope fails?

Comment: @kevfuzz: An ordinary JSF request does two things: first it reconstructs the web interface as it was after the former request, then it applies any changes that the request brings  (otherwise your valueChangeListener would not work), then it renders the changed interface. With request scoped bean, the first phase would fail: JSF would try to reconstruct a dropdown pointing to some arbitrary value that was no longer available among the options. A view scoped bean survives as long as you stay on the same page and use POST, so the values are there. BTW: DON'T ever do anything in the constructor.